# How to read the dictionary from text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text

I have a text file in the below format

```
d = {'EMS':1,'ESC': 2, 'HVAC': 3,'IC' : 4,'ICU' : 5,'IS' : 6,'ITM' : 7,'MBFM' : 8,'PKE' : 9,'RPAS' : 10,'RVC' : 11,'SAS' : 12,'SRS' : 13,'TCU' : 14,'TPMS' : 15,'VCU' : 16,'BMS' : 17,'MCU' :18,'OBC' :19}
```

How do I read the dictionary to find the value a particular value?

I have tried the below code

```
with open(r"filename","r") as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
    print(data)
    for age in data.values():
        if age == search_age:
            name = data[age]
            print (name)
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: @Tejesh Reddy remove the `d = ` from the file. Most likely this is the issue

Comment: This is a valid python module. Rename it to `filename.py` and then `from filename import d`. That's it, now you've got your dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text file is a valid Python code, so if it is from a trusted source, you can simply do:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

and the variable `d` would be loaded with the dict.

If the text file is not from a trusted source, however, you can use `ast.parse` to parse the code, then use `ast.walk` to traverse the abstract syntax tree and look for a `Dict` node. For security reasons, make sure the dict node does not contain any `Call` node before wrapping it as the body of an `Expression` node and compiling it for `eval` to turn it into a real dict stored in variable `d`:

```
import ast
with open("filename") as f:
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(f.read())):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Dict) and \
                not any(isinstance(child, ast.Call) for child in ast.walk(node)):
            d = eval(compile(ast.Expression(body=node), '', 'eval'))
            break
    else:
        print('No valid dict found.')
```

Given your sample input, `d` would become:

```
{'EMS': 1, 'ESC': 2, 'HVAC': 3, 'IC': 4, 'ICU': 5, 'IS': 6, 'ITM': 7, 'MBFM': 8, 'PKE': 9, 'RPAS': 10, 'RVC': 11, 'SAS': 12, 'SRS': 13, 'TCU': 14, 'TPMS': 15, 'VCU': 16, 'BMS': 17, 'MCU': 18, 'OBC': 19}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over both the keys and values:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
    print(data)
    for name, age in data.items():
        if age == search_age:
            print(name)
```

Also, that file looks like a valid JSON object, so you should probably use `json.load` over `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: i tried this i got    File "C:\Python37-32\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    d = {'EMS': 1, 'ESC': 2, 'HVAC': 3,'IC' : 4,'ICU' : 5,'IS' : 6,'ITM' : 7,'MBFM' : 8,'PKE' : 9,'RPAS' : 10,'RVC' : 11,'SAS' : 12,'SRS' : 13,'TCU' : 14,'TPMS' : 15,'VCU' : 16,'BMS' : 17,'MCU' :18,'OBC' :19}
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @TejeshReddy Your file itself is malformed. Take the `d = ` out.

Answer (score 0):

I like the accepted answer by @blhsing, but what if you want a dictionary by a specific variable name? At least that is what I was looking for.

Slight variation of @blhsing 's answer, using `ast.Assign` since that will have `ast.Name` and `ast.Dict` as its children.

```
import ast
from path lib import Path

def walk_file(dict_name, path):
    t = ast.parse(Path(path).read_text())
    return walk(dict_name, t)

def walk(dict_name, t):
    for node in ast.walk(t):
        if (
            isinstance(node, ast.Assign)
            and isinstance(node.value, ast.Dict)
            and node.targets[0].__dict__.get("id") == dict_name
        ):
            if not any(
                isinstance(child, ast.Call) for child in ast.walk(node)
            ):
                value = ast.literal_eval(node.value)
                return value
            else:
                print("uh oh, callables found!")
    else:
        print("No valid dict found.")
```

So for example,

```
blah = """
    d1 = {"hi": 2}
    def foo():
        d2 = {"hmm": {"interesting": [1, 2]}}
    
    d3 = {"sure": "great"}    
"""

t = ast.parse(blah)
for name in ["d1", "d2", "d3"]:
    print(name, walk(name, t))

d1 {'hi': 2}
d2 {'hmm': {'interesting': [1, 2]}}
d3 {'sure': 'great'}
```